# Cannot connect to ssh

Tags: debian, ssh

Hello I type the following command:

> $ ssh -vv root@192.168.11.9

I enter the password correct, but I am getting the following error:

```
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

What extra information you need ???
Here is all the output:

```
  OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to 192.168.11.9 [192.168.11.9] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/citystore/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/citystore/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/citystore/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/citystore/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/citystore/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/citystore/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.11.9" from file "/home/citystore/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/citystore/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
    debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 121/256
    debug2: bits set: 498/1024
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: RSA df:b1:53:f3:0c:1a:b0:57:b5:dd:ab:ae:48:b2:88:c4
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.11.9" from file "/home/citystore/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/citystore/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
    debug1: Host '192.168.11.9' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/citystore/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug2: bits set: 526/1024
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug2: kex_derive_keys
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
    debug2: key: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
    debug2: key: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
    debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
    debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/citystore/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.11.9's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 58 padlen 6 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-
```

On my $HOME/.ssh have only one file:

```
known_hosts
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please try `ssh -vvv root@192.168.11.9` to have a more verbose output.

Answer (score 2):

If the password is accepted it may take a while before a shell is presented. In that case the server is probably performing a name lookup. It depends on the number of configured nameservers how long this timeout last. The connection may even be dropped by the client because it thinks that nothing happens. If you try again a few seconds later you can login succesful.

You can disable this behaviour in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by setting `UseDNS no` or configure the nameservice right so the host can be looked up.

Comment: In the client, right ?

Comment: @KostasC nope, on the server. In your case `192.168.11.9`.

Comment: I don't have access to the server! Only through the ssh! :(

Comment: @KostasC ssh in and just wait until you get a shell.  Could take up to a minute.  Once connected you can edit the sshd_config file and restart the sshd service.

Comment: But I enter the password and I cannot login! Permission denied. says.

Comment: Permission denied looks like root logins are not enabled. In that case have a look at the `PermitRootLogin` directive, also in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server. You first have to login with a regular user account, `su` to root and edit and restart the `ssh` service

Comment: It is elastix server, I don't think exist regular user account, only the root. :(

Comment: Ehm, how do you manage an elastix server where you can not login to? If you have another option to get into the server (like console) change the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` or add a regular user to login with using `ssh`.

Comment: @Lambert, I still can login from the web interface and the database. The physical connect is difficult because the elastix server is inside the rack, which is very difficult to access... :(